# Self-Signed Certificate for IdentityServer 4 Token Signing

Tags: identityserver4

Does the certificate used for signing tokens in IdentityServer4 have to be from a trusted CA in production?

My admittedly limited understanding is that it doesn't. But I can't seem to find a definitive answer either way.

And the obvious follow-up is, *should* it be from a trusted CA?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OpenID Connect does not mandate the usage of X509 certificates at all - you could also use raw RSA or EC keys.

If you want to use X509 you can self-sign them. Most libraries only check if the public key in the discovery document can be used to validate the token.

Some libraries allow additional checks on the certificate - and some environments mandate such checks.

But generally speaking - CA issued certs are not necessary.

Comment: How often do you recommend to rollover the certificate? Do clients look at the expiration date of the signing certificate? Is it okay to have an expiration date 10 year in the future?

Comment: The spec does not mandate to check the expiration date. As long as the signature can be validated with the public key published at the discovery endpoint, everything is fine. That said - for good crypto hygiene you should roll-over your keys periodically - e.g. every couple of months.